# How to unselect the checkbox in the selectableRows by default (when there are no data rows) in mui-datatables?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

If there is data, it is working fine. But while there is no data, it is getting selected by default.

Here is my code, for the options.

```js
 const options = {
  selectableRows: "multiple",
  //selectableRowsOnClick: true,
  rowsSelected: this.state.rowsSelected,
  onRowsSelect: (rowsSelected, allRows) => {
    this.setState({ rowsSelected: allRows.map(row => row.dataIndex) });
  },
  customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData, setSelectedRows) => (
    <div className="mailIconDiv">
      <IconButton
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      >
        <i className="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  ),
};
```

If I run above code, I get empty table.
[image: output]

Can somebody please help me with how to remove it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use selectableRowsHeader in options as below. here data is the collection that is populated to mui-datatable. if data is empty then selectableRowsHeader will be hidden.

```
const options = {
    selectableRows: "multiple",
    selectableRowsHeader: data.length > 0,
    //selectableRowsOnClick: true,
    rowsSelected: this.state.rowsSelected,
    onRowsSelect: (rowsSelected, allRows) => {
        this.setState({rowsSelected: allRows.map(row => row.dataIndex)});
    },
    customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData, setSelectedRows) => (
        <div className="mailIconDiv">
            <IconButton
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
            >
                <i className="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    ),
};
```